# Accessing parent class method error

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance

I am trying to learn super implementation in Python and I have tried various help threads on SO but I am not able to implement the following code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname + ", " + str(self.age)

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, staffnum):
        super(Employee, self).__init__(first, last, age)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def __str__(self):
        return super(Employee, self).__str__() + ", " +  self.staffnumber


x = Person("Marge", "Simpson", 36)
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", 28, "1007")

print(x)
print(y)
```

What is wrong with this syntax in above code?

```
return super(Employee, self).__str__() + ", " +  self.staffnumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7 there are leftovers of the old hierarchy. Not all classes inherit from `object`, which is the default in Python 3. If you do not explicitly inherit `object` Python will use old style objects, which fail with `Super` which depends on this.

All you need to do is explicitly make sure all your objects eventually inherit `object`:

```
class Person(object):
```

In Python 3 this is 'fixed'.

An alternative is to forego super in favor of using the methods as class methods, which will work with both types of objects:

```
Person.__init__(self,first,last,age)
Person.__str__(self)
```